# Reach other computer from the local

Tags: networking

I learned from the book "Harley Hhan's Guide to Unix and Linux".
In chapter 3 of "The Unix Connection", it instruct to establish a local area network.

> You can see this illustrated in Figure 3-6. In Figure 3-6, the network connections between the PC and the three Unix hosts are via cables, as in a traditional network. However, any type of network connection will do. In particular, you can use a wireless connection.
>
> Here is an example. Let’s say you have three geeky friends, Manny, Moe and Jack. Each of you has a laptop computer that runs Unix. You use Debian Linux; Manny uses Fedora Core Linux; Moe uses Gentoo Linux; and Jack uses FreeBSD. (Jack always was a bit odd.)
>
> You get together for a Unix party (that is, computers, caffeinated drinks, and junk food), and you decide that each person should have access to the other three computers. First, each of you creates user accounts on your own computer for the other three people. (I won’t go into the details here, but it’s not hard.)

[image]

I created user account on two computer but have no idea how to reach another from one.

Do I miss any points? Could you offer any hints?

Comment: Try `ssh` it stands for secure shell. Search this site and Google about how to set up.

Comment: If I want to login to my pe2900 server; I `ssh pe2900` and I'm in.  I have password login enabled (using keys) and my machine knows the ip address by name. If I wanted to login using a different account to an address unknown to my box (or DNS), I'd user `ssh user@192.168.1.3` (where user & 192.168.1.3 where whatever was to be used).  I'd expect to be asked for a password (my example pe2900 won't do that; I've disabled that; and only allows login from certain accounts & using keys).  `ssh` is just a secure version of `rsh` (remote shell)

Comment: Looks strange. If you really obtained the book, then you can read about SSH on the page 49 (two pages after this figure)... But anyway thanks for book suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I want to login to my pe2900 server; I

```
ssh pe2900
```

and I'm in.

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$ ssh pe2900
Last login: Sun Jan  6 22:03:34 2019
..  /* redacted welcome & stat messages */
[guiverc@pe2900 shared]$
```

I have password login enabled (using keys) and my machine knows the ip address by name.

If I wanted to login using a different account to an address unknown to my box (or DNS), I would

```
ssh user@192.168.1.3
```

*where user & 192.168.1.3 are whatever are your user and ip.address of machine you want to use). I'd expect to be asked for a password (my example pe2900 won't do that; I've disabled that; and only allows login from certain accounts, addresses & using keys)*.

`ssh` is just a secure version of `rsh` (remote shell)