# Auto login to ssh with X11 Forwarding

Tags: ssh, xorg

I'm trying to make a script to log me into my server via ssh and run programs via X11 Forwarding. I currently do this with:

```
ssh -XC USER@SERVER
```

but I also want it to log in with my password. I recently found the command sshpass but I can't find anything about it doing X11 forwarding.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about `sshpass` but private-public key based authentication works well.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: See [Ubuntu help page on this subject](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and also see the public key based authentication section of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107987/connect-two-computers-with-ssh-in-a-home-lan/1108044#1108044)

Answer (score 1):

`sshpass` is used [this way](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass), ie. you have to run an actual `ssh` command via `sshpass`. In your case it will be:

```
sshpass -p password ssh -XC USER@SERVER
```

So `sshpass` by itself doesn't have to know anything about X forwarding, because `ssh` handles that. The only job `sshpass` does is provide the password to `ssh`.

Please be aware that specifying a password on the command line (like in the example above) is insecure. `sshpass` offers alternative methods to provide a password: from file or from an environment variable (details in link).

However, the best method to use `ssh` without having to type a password is to configure key-based authentication, as @user68186 mentioned. [Here](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/) is a tutorial how to do that.