# Run Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 using OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, 20.10

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 in my Raspberry Pi 4. I don't have any form of display to connect directly to raspberry pi.

I want to use Raspberry Pi using OpenSSH.

Is there a way to enable OpenSSH in the boot volume for Ubuntu Desktop similar to how it works for Ubuntu Server.

I even tried adding a file without an extension and naming it ssh in the boot volume, but still no luck.

Comment: Did you install the server or the desktop version of Ubuntu 20.10? If you installed the server, you should have selected to install openssh-server at the time of installation. If desktop, then you have to temporarily connect a display and keyboard and install the openssh-server and set it up. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107987/connect-two-computers-with-ssh-in-a-home-lan/1108044#1108044)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Desktop does not include an ssh server. There is nothing installed for your magic file to activate.

- You must install openssh-server, which cannot be done headlessly on Ubuntu Desktop. It's trivial to install (`sudo apt install openssh-server`), it's simply not included with Ubuntu Desktop (most desktop users don't need it).

  Remember to safely configure your ssh server to use keys. Password-protected ssh servers are strongly discouraged on internet-facing systems.
- Ubuntu Server is different: Server includes the ssh server out-of-the-box, and the new 21.04 server installer even helps you configure the ssh server securely.