# Allowing outside connections to my Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, server, dns, sftp

How do i allow and set it up so that my friends can connect to my ubuntu server to access the server files through WinSCP?

I believe i have the port forwards correct.

I KNOW i have permissions for users correct.

I don't know if we are using the correct host name to connect though.

- And with this, would it be possible to add DNS service settings to a site that i have so they can just connect through the site address like "xxxx.com"?

Edit:

- I am running Version 21.10 of Ubuntu
- Port 22 has been forwarded using UFW, and confirmed and double checked with GUFW
- When trying to connect (using external IP) through WinSCP on that port 22, i get a connection refused (used to get timed out)
- I had already previously tested that i can in fact connect locally with no problems

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395860/edit) and add information about exactly how you have set up port forwarding. Try connecting with the external IP address. If your server is at home you can find out your external IP address by Googling **what is my ip address**. Update your question with the results (exact errors) of connecting with the external IP address.

Comment: Reduce the number of variables. Verify that you can successfully connect from a different machine *on the same LAN* before moving on to Port Forwarding and DDNS and other complexities.

Comment: Edited the question with the extra information that yall were requesting of

@user68186

Comment: Port forwarding has nothing to do with `ufw`. You have to do the port forwarding in your home router. Port forwarding has nothing to do with Ubuntu, and is generally off-topic here. See [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360840/how-to-access-home-ssh-server-from-outside-via-the-internet/1360963#1360963) for some rough ideas about how to do it. Edit your question and leave a note in comments (as you did above) if you still have problems.