# SSH - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: networking, ssh

Before I get into this, I just wanted to say that I've read many posts about this problem and none of them were helpful. I tried changing the permissions and it didn't work.

> Permission of ~/.ssh folder must be 700, ~/.ssh/id_rsa : 600, ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub : 644

I've got two Ubuntu 20.04 machines, a desktop and a laptop. Using password based authentication, I was able to copy both public keys to the other computer using ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.x.x. I then changed the following lines in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on both machines:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

When I attempted to connect via ssh using public key from the desktop to the laptop, it worked fine. However, when I tried the opposite, laptop to desktop via public key, I got Permission denied (publickey). When I switch back from Public Key Authentication to Password authentication, it works. I wanted to post the ssh -vvv output but askubuntu marked it as spam.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use the command `ssh-copy-id` in the laptop pointing to the IP address of the desktop? Once you do that you should be able to `ssh` from the laptop to the desktop without entering the desktop's password. See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107987/connect-two-computers-with-ssh-in-a-home-lan/1108044#1108044) for a step-by-step how to setup the public key. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1380171/edit) and add all the new information.

Comment: `ssh`, on the sending node, and `sshd`, on the receiving node, exchange a list of authentication methods they offer/accept, and agree on a method they have in common. You can see the lists by adding the "`-v`" option to your `ssh` command, and can change the configuration. See `man sshd_config`

Comment: Did you restart the `sshd` daemons? `sshd` only reads configuration when it starts up.