# ssh: challengeresponseauthentication in 22.04 Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, 22.04

I upgraded to 22.04 and used Duo with Pam from MFA. After the upgrade, I no longer see an option for `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes` in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and keyboard-interactive logins and Duo MFA no longer work.

Answer (score 17):

Seems like the `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` option was replaced by `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I just enabled 2FA with pam_google_authenticator.so as described in the [Ubuntu Community Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/configure-ssh-to-use-two-factor-authentication/13956).

Note that the config file says: "beware issues with some PAM modules and threads". So other PAM modules might not work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply in my old sshd_config I had AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive, do I still need that or is there a replacement for that statement?

Comment: @mark could you explain the difference between `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`. Is there any reference on that?